# Different number posts per page based on custom post type term id

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, custom-post-type-archives

Trying to cobble together a function from various suggestions that sets the number of posts per page based on the custom post type category in question. For instance, an "Alphabetical" category contains 3500+ posts, so I want pagination, but a child category "A" contains 100 posts and I want to show them all without pagination. The term_id for "A" is 1858, for "Alphabetical" is 1853. Can I check for specific term ids in a conditional? Not like this of course, which was just guessing...

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'limit_change_posts_archive');
function limit_change_posts_archive($query){
    if ( is_archive && is_tax( 'pdsh_categories' ) && is_term( 1858 ) {
    $query->set('posts_per_page', -1);
}
return $query;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it with `pre_get_posts`. With your current code there are multiple syntax errors. You have write it this way

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'limit_change_posts_archive');
function limit_change_posts_archive($query){
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_archive() && is_tax( 'pdsh_categories' ) && is_term( 1858 )) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', -1);
    }
    return $query;
}
```

As `is_term` is deprecated a different approach can be like this:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'limit_change_posts_archive');
function limit_change_posts_archive($query){
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_archive() && is_tax( 'pdsh_categories', 1858 )) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', -1);
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Again this above code needs to be tested.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah, my code was messy, I see the errors. But, just tested your pass and it actually doesn't quite do the job either... the post limit for the "Alphabetical" archive 1853 is being set to -1 also, as if the 3rd conditional isn't doing anything. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you try now? I've updated the code to check main query

Comment: Also `is_term` is deprecated. Can you var_dump the `$query` and show me the result?

Comment: @SabbirHasan, your code could actually be written as: `if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_tax( 'pdsh_categories', 1858 ) ) { $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 ); }`.. :) Check the [`is_tax()` reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tax/).

Comment: Thanks for pointing. I'll be updating the answer.

Comment: Thanks Sabbir. Yes, the second iteration works. With additional elseif...
`add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'limit_change_posts_archive');
function limit_change_posts_archive($query){
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_archive() && is_tax( 'pdsh_categories', 1853 )) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 100);
    } 
 elseif ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_archive() && is_tax( 'pdsh_categories', 1858 )) {
  $query->set('posts_per_page', -1);
    } 
    return $query;
}`

Comment: How would I add a second sub category to the elseif? i.e. { 1858, 1859 } ?

Comment: You can use *is_tax* like this `is_tax('pdsh_categories',[1853,1858])`. You can see available possibilities here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tax/

Comment: Thanks Sabbir. And thanks @SallyCJ too... I missed that you helped out. I don't see that kind of array(?) example on the is_tax page but I'll keep looking. Anyway, much appreciated.

Comment: Glad I could help, @markw. And as for that array thing, if you look at the function [parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tax/#parameters), the second one (`$term`) is actually described as "*(int|string|int[]|string[]) (Optional)* Term ID, name, slug, or array of such to check against.", so you can pass an array of (term) IDs, names or slugs. Also, instead of that `&& is_archive() && is_tax( ... )`, you could actually simply do `&& is_tax( ... )`. :)